# JPanel Constantly Being Repainted Due To setOpaque(false) Method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparent, repaint

I am creating a game of Snake and have come across the issue of having to use a JLayeredPane. I have drawn the board using the DrawBoard class which constantly must be repainted according to a timer. I have to assign a random colour to 3 fruit I am placing on the board, as I cannot place this in the DrawBoard class (as it is constantly being repainted and therefore the random colour keeps on changing for every repaint) I have had to make a separate JPanel, c2. c2 is then put this into a JLayeredFrame along with the container (containing the drawBoard component) JPanel so that the c2 can sit on top of container -- effectively overlaying the fruit onto the board as to allow manual repainting of the fruit component every time the fruit is collected to set a random colour.

As I am drawing the fruit onto the board, I must set the background of the components and the JPanel to be transparent, so that you can see the board below. The problem, I have identified is that when c2.setOpaque(false) is called, the c2 JPanel keeps on repainting itself, therefore producing random colours continuously for the fruit.

The JLayeredPane is then placed into a JFrame.

How would it be possible to make the c2 JPanel have a transparent background without it calling itself?

**Board Class -- this is where the JFrame is**

```
    public Board() {
        boardBack(g);
        startGame();
    }

    public void boardBack(Graphics g) {
        questionBox = new QuestionBox();
        drawBoard = new DrawBoard();
        points = new Points();
        fruit = new Fruit();
        filler = new Filler();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JPanel c2 = new JPanel();
        JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);

        container.add(questionBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(points, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(drawBoard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        c2.add(fruit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c2.add(filler, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        filler.setOpaque(false);
        fruit.setOpaque(false);
        //This is where the problem exists, 
        //when removed I cannot see the drawBoard component below,
        //but it no longer repaints.
        c2.setOpaque(false);

        container.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 720);
        c2.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 720);

        pane.add(c2, new Integer(2));
        pane.add(container, new Integer(1));

        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 720));

        frame.add(pane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

In this class I also have a actionPerformed method and Timer which does that action for every tick. There is no recalling of the fruit component within this.

**Fruit class**

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Fruit extends JPanel {

    public static Color red = new Color(8005929);
    public static Color brown = new Color(9067566);
    public static Color purple = new Color(6684774);

    public static Dimension dim4 = new Dimension(600, 600);

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(dim4.width, dim4.height);
    }

        Random rand = new Random();
        public int selectColour;
        //The structure of the array is as follows
        // [0] - fruit1 colour
        // [1] - fruit2 colour
        // [2] - fruit3 colour
        public int[] colourSelected = new int[3];

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //This allows us to select a random colour for the fruit to be assigned.
        //Where selectColour = 0 refers to the colour red
        //Where selectColour = 1 refers to the colour brown
        //Where selectColour = 2 refers to the colour purple
        int selectColour = rand.nextInt(3);

        switch (selectColour) {
        case 0:
            colourSelected[0] = selectColour;
            g.setColor(red);
            break;
        case 1:
            colourSelected[0] = selectColour;
            g.setColor(brown);
            break;
        case 2:
            colourSelected[0] = selectColour;
            g.setColor(purple);
            break;
        }

        //Draws the fruit at the point of the fruit
        g.fillRect(Board.fruit1.x * Board.SCALE, Board.fruit1.y * Board.SCALE,
                Board.SCALE, Board.SCALE);

        //This draws the second fruit
        g.setColor(brown);
        g.fillRect(Board.fruit2.x * Board.SCALE, Board.fruit2.y * Board.SCALE,
                Board.SCALE, Board.SCALE);

        //This draws the third fruit
        g.setColor(purple);
        g.fillRect(Board.fruit3.x * Board.SCALE, Board.fruit3.y * Board.SCALE,
                Board.SCALE, Board.SCALE);

    }
```

This shows the issue when run I have put a `System.out.println()` within the `paintComponent()` method to show the problem.

When setOpaque(false) is still in the code (the bottom left fruit continuously changes colour)

[image]

When removed

[image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you don't control the painting process, painting could occur for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control

Second, painting should paint the current state of the component and not contain any logic.

Move you color generation out of the `paintComponent` to a method that you `Timer` can call instead and repaint the component whenever you call this method

Comment: But that wouldn't make a difference as it constantly repaints the component regardless of where the setColour is as I eventually have to call this method back into the paintComponent to set the colour of the fruit.

Comment: Also, as I said, when I remove the c2.setOpaque(false) it no longer repaints itself.

Comment: Provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem. Transparent components need to be revalidate when ever one or more components that overlap it are updated, so it's possible that some other part of your code is been updated and forcing it to be repainted...